# How did Artorias' Sword get that big?

Tags: dark-souls

When you first find Sif, he is weilding Artorias' greatsword, and the thing is as long as a bus! However, when you find him later in the DLC, he is only around twice the size of the Chosen Undead, and his sword is much smaller (*wink*).

Is there anything in the lore about how the sword grew/what caused it?

Comment: The fact that you can reconstruct Artorias' sword from Sif's soul suggests that it's not a simple material object, but some kind of supernatural essence that different objects can be imbued with. Maybe after Artorias' death, that essence has been extracted from the original weapon and put into a greatsword the right size for a giant wolf to wield with its mouth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general, rather than Dark Souls-specific answer: It is a common trope that [gods can take whatever shape they want](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AFormYouAreComfortableWith), but they are still slaves to [narrativium](http://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Narrativium). So they usually end up looking like big humanoids when they want to intimidate. From there it's not much of a stretch to imagine that **any weapon a god wields will change to fit them.**

---

[A lore-based theory](https://youtu.be/DwsZ_zd65hU?t=826) is that they are actually different swords, and the one that Sif is wielding is actually *part* of Sif.